# Can't compile program for PIC because of a define statement

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, ide

I am trying to compile an example program from Microchip using MPLABX. It looks like the IDE is not including the "xc.h" file becuase of the following code:

if defined(__XC)

inlcude xc.h

The "inlcude xc.h" is grayed out so I'm assuming the software seems to think __XC is not defined. Attached is a picture as well along with the error message. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Grayed out doesn't mean it can't find the file to include.  That's just the color the IDE uses to indicate code inside the "#if defined" block.  I'd have a look at line 39.

Comment: In my other projects that work, grayed out means the IDE does not include it. If the define statement worked, the code would be colorful

Comment: You could try just doing `#define __XC` and see if it fixes things.

Comment: you sadly scrolled past the actual error that lead to make aborting. So, no helping you :( also, [pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are bad, and so are [pictures of error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: #define __XC did not work, and I included the code in the text as the "downvote" article said to do. And posting error messages definitely helps. I edited the question to include the full error message

Comment: Posting error messages helps.  It is better to post the text rather than a picture of the text.  In other words:  no screen shots of error messages.

Comment: I will remember that in the future.

Comment: why wait for the future? ... you can edit your post today

Answer (score -1):

So I switched the C standard from C99 to C90 in the "XC8 global options" and it worked. No idea why.... apparently that error message is very generic and could be generated for hundreds of reasons.

After that worked, I switched the C standard back to C99 and it compiled as well. FUBAR

Comment: https://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=1056620&mpage=1